# Android SDK broken after Visual Studio 2019 update

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, android-sdk-tools

I have been creating a Xamarin forms application using Visual studio 2019 for the past two months now however after completing the latest update for Visual Studio 2019, I am now receiving the following error when trying to build the application.

`Error Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please click here to configure.`

I thought that possibly the update had uninstalled Android SDK however below you can see that Android SDk is in fact installed.

[image: AndroidSDK]

As well as this, emulator `28.0.25` is also installed. Has anyone else had any issues with the Android SDK after the latest Visual Studio update?

I have read [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/176310/xamarinandroid-for-visual-studio-requires-android.html) that uninstalling the SDK should fix this issue however what do I uninstall? Would this be the Android SDK Tools + Android SDK Platform-tools + Android SDK Build-Tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue I uninstalled `Android SDK Tools`, `Android SDK Platform-Tools` and `Android SDK Build-Tools` and re-installed them. I then got the same error however looking into the logs located in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\XamarinDeviceManager`
I found that there was a big error log stating how Component Android SDK Platforms were not found on the system.

I closed Visual Studio, cleaned the solution and built it and it seems to have fixed the bug.

Comment: Same here. After the project is re-opened, there's a popup prompting to install the correct versions of Android SDK compoments. It doesn't even need to open Android SDK Manager window again.